# How to Reload NavigationItem Title

Tags: ios, uinavigationitem

I've define a button to change navigationItem title by using below method.

```
self.navigationItem.title
```

However, the title doesn't change immediately before I re-push to this view.
Is there have a method like [tableView reload] to reload the title and make it shows changed immediately?

Comment: How about just `self.title`? Assuming `self` is a `UIViewController` subclass...

Comment: actually the title property has been changed but the last one didn't shows up before the view did reload.

Comment: Are you doing this on a different thread? If so, use `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{self.title = @"Text";});`

Comment: thx, but there only one main runloop

Answer (score 1):

this will help you

```
 self.title = @"Some title here";
```

Comment: it's not working well just as the way I've used.  But thx for your helped.

Comment: do you have navigationController or a property (navigation bar)

Comment: yes I have a navigationController. And the title is refresh to last while this view was pushed.

Comment: does it take title from the init method

Comment: nope, it take title from a button pressed event which included serial names. Title changes when this button pressed.